# Where is the detailed documentation of MSBuild parameter: GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder

Tags: properties, msbuild, arguments, pipeline

I knew a lot of developers use this parameter /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true to output the solution's projects to different folders. Is there any official documentation to explain the detail of this parameter and other similar parameters? Thanks

I tried it in Azaure DevOps pipeline and it works, but need more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

`GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder` is in the [MSBuild source](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/b705a20b75c2b7e3b519d75146adff041869e7a2/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#LL234-L235) but it appears there is no official documentation.